# Elevation not shown in PopupMenu in Android

Tags: android, menu, android-5.0-lollipop, popupmenu

Elevation is not working in PopupMenu. I tried to implement the elevation for PopupMenu using styles.xml but not working. I want to implement shadow for PopupMenu [Screenshot for an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bmGJ.png)

Implemented Popupmenu in Code

```
 Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MyPopupMenu);
                   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, vItem);
                    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(TaskDetailActivity.this);
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.show();
```

Styles.xml

```
    <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
            <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/md_white_1000</item>
            <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
            <item name="android:popupElevation" 
           tools:targetApi="lollipop">@dimen/_20sdp</item> </style>
```